# Restkit 0.20 complex relationship mapping

Tags: objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Consider the following NSManagedObjects

1) ITask

```
@interface ITask : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * serialNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *taskSharedWith;

@end
```

represented by

```
<entity name="ITask" representedClassName="ITask" syncable="YES">
    <attribute name="serialNumber" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
    <relationship name="taskSharedWith" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="ITaskSharedWith" inverseName="task" inverseEntity="ITaskSharedWith" syncable="YES"/>
</entity>
<entity name="ITaskSharedWith" representedClassName="ITaskSharedWith" syncable="YES">
    <relationship name="task" optional="YES" minCount="1" maxCount="1" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="ITask" inverseName="taskSharedWith" inverseEntity="ITask" syncable="YES"/>
    <relationship name="user" optional="YES" minCount="1" maxCount="1" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="IUser" inverseName="taskSharedWith" inverseEntity="IUser" syncable="YES"/>
</entity>
<entity name="IUser" representedClassName="IUser" syncable="YES">
    <attribute name="userDisplayName" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
    <attribute name="userEmail" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
    <attribute name="userFqn" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
    <attribute name="userManager" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
    <attribute name="userName" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
    <attribute name="userProperties" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
    <relationship name="taskComments" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="ITaskComments" inverseName="user" inverseEntity="ITaskComments" syncable="YES"/>
    <relationship name="taskSharedWith" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="ITaskSharedWith" inverseName="user" inverseEntity="ITaskSharedWith" syncable="YES"/>
    <relationship name="userVideoRecordings" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="ITaskVideos" inverseName="user" inverseEntity="ITaskVideos" syncable="YES"/>
</entity>
```

2) IUser

```
@interface IUser : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userDisplayName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userEmail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userFqn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userProperties;

@end
```

Here's the incoming JSON

```
[
  {
    "SerialNumber": "3_9",
    "DelegatedUsers": [
      {
        "Name": "K2:DENALLIX\\k2service"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my current ITask mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *taskMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"ITask" inManagedObjectStore:mos];
//primary key
taskMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"serialNumber"];
[taskMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"SerialNumber":@"serialNumber",
 }];
 RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"IUser" inManagedObjectStore:mos];
 userMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"userFqn"];
 [userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"Name":@"userFqn",
 }];

RKEntityMapping *sharedWithMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"ITaskSharedWith" inManagedObjectStore:mos];
[sharedWithMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"DelegatedUsers"
                                                                                  toKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                withMapping:userMapping]];

[taskMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"DelegatedUsers"
                                                                            toKeyPath:@"taskSharedWith"
                                                                          withMapping:sharedWithMapping]];
```

Restkit gives me this error

```
2013-05-29 00:15:48.647 k2Mobile[22389:c07] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:651 Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'DelegatedUsers' to 'taskSharedWith'
2013-05-29 00:15:48.648 k2Mobile[22389:c07] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:862 Starting mapping operation...
Unknown.m:0: error: -[TaskMappingsFixture test_That_Task_Fetch_Mapping_is_Correct] : [<__NSCFConstantString 0x97d8fa0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DelegatedUsers.
```

Users are already populated in the db, so I just need to insert the entry into the ITaskSharedWith table, which has many-to-many relationship to ITask and IUser